# Trying to create a randomly generated test

Tags: java

> I have already created a GUI for this assignment and now need to figure out how to execute each option. I need to create a test that can use Math.random() to generate equations that end in a whole number, the user can choose from easy, medium, or hard, with each option using a different number range. The user can also choose from addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division, and can choose multiple for one test. I am trying to write code that will store each value into an array of values for each equation (aVal1 being the first value for an addition equation and aVal2 being the second) But when I try to run the program and print out what aVal[0] has calculated into, it returns as 0. It seems like the program is not reading my equation like I want it to. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



public class MathQuiz extends JFrame 
implements ActionListener {

private JLabel questionNmbr = new JLabel
("Select # of      questions:");
private JTextField questionTxt = new JTextField(8);
private JLabel questionTypes = new JLabel
("Select wanted question types:");
private JCheckBox addition = new JCheckBox("+");
private JCheckBox subtraction = new JCheckBox("-");
private JCheckBox multiplication = new JCheckBox("x");
private JCheckBox division = new JCheckBox("÷");
private JLabel difficulty = new JLabel
("Choose difficulty:");
private JRadioButton easy = new JRadioButton("Easy");
private JRadioButton medium = new JRadioButton("Medium");
private JRadioButton hard = new JRadioButton("Hard");
private JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

//whether or not each is chosen
private int aNmbr = 0;
private int sNmbr = 0;
private int mNmbr = 0;
private int dNmbr = 0;

//how many questions each operation will have
private int aQs = 0;
private int sQs = 0;
private int mQs = 0;
private int dQs = 0;

public MathQuiz() {

    //grouping radio btns
    ButtonGroup level = new ButtonGroup();
    level.add(easy);
    level.add(medium);
    level.add(hard);
    easy.addActionListener(this);
    medium.addActionListener(this);
    hard.addActionListener(this);
    submit.addActionListener(this);

    setTitle("Quiz");
    setSize(400, 400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    add(questionNmbr);
    add(questionTxt);
    add(questionTypes);
    add(addition);
    add(subtraction);
    add(multiplication);
    add(division);
    add(difficulty);
    add(easy);
    add(medium);
    add(hard);
    add(submit);


    setVisible(true);


}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object obj = e.getSource();
    Object obj2 = e.getSource();

    //prints out the test
    if (obj == submit) {
        int QNmbr = Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText());

        int[] aVal1 = 
new int[Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText())];
        int[] aVal2 = 
new int[Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText())];

        try {
            Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException f) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                    "Please enter a number");
        }



        if (obj == addition) {
            aNmbr = 1;
        }

        if (obj == subtraction) {
            sNmbr = 1;
        }

        if (obj == multiplication) {
            mNmbr = 1;
        }

        if (obj == division) {
            dNmbr = 1;
        }


        //if easy is chosen
        if (obj == easy) {


            if(obj2 == addition) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
                    aVal1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
                    System.out.print(aVal1[0]);
                }
                for(int j = 0; j < 
Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText()); j++){
                    aVal2[j] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
                }

            }
            /*if(obj2 == subtraction) {
                while (i < 
(Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText())) / (aNmbr + sNmbr +
 mNmbr + dNmbr)) {
                    aVal1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
                    i++;
                }
                while (j < 
Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText())) {
                    aVal2[j] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
                    j++;
                }

            }
            if(obj2 == multiplication) {
                while (i < 
(Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText())) / (aNmbr + sNmbr +
 mNmbr + dNmbr)) {
                    aVal1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
                    i++;
                }
                while (j < 
Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText())) {
                    aVal2[j] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
                    j++;
                }

            }
            if(obj2 == division) {
                while (i < 
(Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText())) / (aNmbr + sNmbr +
 mNmbr + dNmbr)) {
                    aVal1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
                    i++;
                }
                while (j < 
Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText())) {
                    aVal2[j] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
                    j++;


                }

            }
*/

        }

        if (obj == medium) {

        }

        if (obj == hard) {

        }

        System.out.println(aVal1[0]);
    }

}






}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText());` the result of this call isn't been assigned to anything, but since you're doing to before hand (and assigning it to `QNmbr` I question it's value

Comment: It's not possible for `if (obj == submit) {` AND `if (obj == addition) {` (or any of the other evaluations to `obj`) to be `true` at the same time.  Instead, you need to be looking at the actual component states

Comment: That's what it was I needed to use .isSelected() instead of (obj == addition). My Math.random() is printing the right integers now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's just break this down for a second...

```
Object obj = e.getSource();
Object obj2 = e.getSource();

//prints out the test
if (obj == submit) {
    //...
    if (obj == addition) {...}

    if (obj == subtraction) {...}

    if (obj == multiplication) {...}

    if (obj == division) {...}

    //if easy is chosen
    if (obj == easy) {
        if (obj2 == addition) {...}
    }

    if (obj == medium) {...}

    if (obj == hard) {...}

    System.out.println(aVal1[0]);
```

if `obj` is equal to `submit`, it's impossible for `obj` to be equal to `addition` or any other object.  If `obj` is equal to `addition` (or any other object), there's no way to enter the `if (obj == submit) {` block any way, so the whole thing makes no sense.

Also `obj` and `obj2` are the same thing, so, more confusion.

Also, this makes no sense...

```
int QNmbr = Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText());

try {
    Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException f) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
            "Please enter a number");
}
```

The exception will already have been trigged when doing `int QNmbr = Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText());`.  So, if you want to trap this, the whole block of logic must be trapped in the `try-catch` block, not just the conversion ... I mean, what do you do after the `catch` - how do you know an exception has occurred?

Instead, you need to look at the components themselves and make decisions based on there states, for example...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object obj = e.getSource();
    //prints out the test
    if (obj == submit) {
        int QNmbr = Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText());

        int[] aVal1 = new int[Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText())];
        int[] aVal2 = new int[Integer.parseInt(questionTxt.getText())];

        aNmbr += addition.isSelected() ? 1 : 0;
        aNmbr += subtraction.isSelected() ? 1 : 0;
        aNmbr += multiplication.isSelected() ? 1 : 0;
        aNmbr += division.isSelected() ? 1 : 0;
        if (easy.isSelected()) {
            if (addition.isSelected()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < QNmbr; i++) {
                    aVal1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
                    aVal2[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 11);
                    System.out.print(aVal1[0]);
                }
            }
        } else if (medium.isSelected()) {

        } else if (hard.isSelected()) {

        }
        System.out.println(aVal1[0]);
    }
}
```

I'd also recommend taking a look at:

- [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and [How to Use Spinners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) for controlling user input (ie numbers only)
- [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) as an alternative for when you want to limit the choice a user can make (to one option, obviously)